# JavaScript to submit only files which are under 1 mb

Tags: javascript, file-upload, multipartform-data, form-data

I need to perform image validation in my project which only under 1-MB files should be uploaded ,
I have try this approach to create new formData which are only contains file under 1-MB.

'''

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{route('addFiles.post'}}" onsubmit="return checkFileSizes();">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
  function checkFileSizes() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');
    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
      var filesToUpload = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        var fileSize = fileInput.files[i].size;
        if (fileSize <= 1048576) {
          filesToUpload.push(fileInput.files[i]);
        }
      }
      if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
        // Create a new FormData object and add the valid files to it
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var j = 0; j < filesToUpload.length; j++) {
          formData.append('files[]', filesToUpload[j]);
        }
        // Submit the form with the valid files
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "{{route('addFiles.post'}}", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
      } else {
        alert('No files selected or all selected files are larger than 1 MB');
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

'''

but Problem is that form is sill uploading files with the larger size, and in response is 500.

Comment: Do you have any steps to reproduce? I see this is working fine.

Comment: are you sending two files together ?,i'm sending two files one is 500kb and other is 6 mb ,both files are send then server responded with Max post size error. By the code it only needs to send 500kb file.

Comment: I guess you are sending files to the server two times. First time through xhr request which does filter out files greater than 1mb. but after function returns true which in turn submit the form again. This time both the files gets sent.

Comment: Check your browser console network request once you click submit. Do you see any outgoing calls for addFiles?

Comment: nope, network tab only shows one request.

Comment: And after that page is submitted and refreshed right?

Comment: Yes ,page goes to another route

Comment: Right. So that's your second post which sends file to the server. You can just add return false from the js function in any case as it is already sending files.

Comment: After xhr.send you can add your other logic such as displaying success msg and/or refreshing page.

Comment: I tried that now page is not redirecting but server response is 419.